# Dimension and subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $F$ and $G$ be two subspaces of a vector space $E$. What is the relationship between dim $(F+G)$ and dim $(F \oplus G)$ ?

We know that dim $(F \oplus G)$ = dim $(F)$ + dim $(G)$ = dim $(F+G)$ + dim $(F \cap G)$ no ?

In addition to that, I need to find an example where dim $(F+G)$ $\neq$ dim $(F \oplus G)$

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the sum is not a direct sum you could get no new dimensions.

Consider $e_i$ $(i=1,2,3)$ the canonical base for Euclidean space.

Take $V=\langle e_1,e_2\rangle$ and $W=\langle e_2,e_3\rangle$.

So $\dim(V)+\dim(W)=2+2=4$ but $\dim(V+W)=3$.

In general, $$\dim(V+W)=\dim(V)+\dim(W)-\dim(V\cap W)$$ and if the sum is a direct sum then $V\cap W=\{0\}$, which has dimension zero, so $$\dim(V\oplus W)=\dim(V)+\dim(W).$$

Answer (score 0):

$\mathbb{R}+\mathbb{R}=\mathbb{R}$ so  $dim(\mathbb{R}+\mathbb{R})=dim\mathbb{R}=1$, considering $\mathbb{R}$ is a vector space over itself, but $dim(\mathbb{R}\oplus\mathbb{R})=2\neq dim\mathbb{R}=1$

Comment: So what is the relation between the two dimensions ?